# Plot compiled function with LogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting, compile

I have a compiled function which I can plot without issue using `Plot`. However, when I use `LogLinearPlot` I get the message:

> Argument x at position 1 should be a machine-size real number.

The following MWE gets the same message:

```
compFn = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, x^2 + 2]
LogLinearPlot[compFn[x], {x, 1, 100}]
```

Ultimately my goal is to plot the function with a logarithmic scale for the $ x $-axis.

Comment: does this work as a work-around: `Plot[cf[x], {x, 0, 100}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {{Log, Exp}, None}]`?

Comment: .. or this: ``Plot[cf[Exp@x], {x, Log@1, Log@100}, 
 Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], Automatic}]``?

Comment: What version and OS are you using? Your code works as expected with v11.3 on a Mac.

Comment: A wild guess, maybe you need to `Clear[x]`. BTW, your code runs no warning and no error on my side.

Comment: @BobHanlon Windows 10 and Mathematica 10.2.  I have v11 on another computer so may try to transfer it over and run it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 11.3, your code works without issue. I guess in an earlier version, Mathematica might try to evaluate your compiled function with a symbolic `x` which leads to the error. Try the following, which wraps your compiled code in a function that does only allow numerical values

```
With[{compFn = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, x^2 + 2]},
  f[x_?NumericQ] := compFn[x]
  ];
LogLinearPlot[f[x], {x, 1, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In MMA 11  code is working.

```
compFn = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, x^2 + 2]
LogLinearPlot[compFn[x], {x, 1, 100}, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue,
     FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]