# Numerical contour plot of compiled function

Tags: plotting, compile

I have come across a problem in Mathematica when I have tried to plot the contours of a compiled function.

```
f  = Compile[{{x}, {y}}, x^2 + y^2];
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0.1, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]
```

this works perfectly but suppose I want to only plot a single contour:

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0.1, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]
```

this then returns the error

[image: compiled function error]

but still plots the contour correctly. Evaluating `f[x, y] == 0.1` gives `x^2 + y^2 == 0.1` along with the same error message as the output so it's clear that the problem is that in order to plot the contour specified Mathematica requires the equation for the contour to be in symbolic form suggesting that `ContourPlot` is using a symbolic method to solve the problem.

However this is no good for anything difficult. I have a function `longFunc[x,y]` which is an extremely complicated expression and hence must be compiled and evaluated numerically. When I do a simple `ContourPlot` it works perfectly but if I specify a contour `longFunc[x,y]==0.5` it falls back to a symbolic method and doesn't return an answer for a very long time.

So the question is: Is there an option within `ContourPlot` to force Mathematica to search for a solution to the equality using a numerical method?

Thank you!

Related:

[ContourPlot is slow and unwieldy and generates a large-data graphic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58912/contourplot-is-slow-and-unwieldy-and-generates-a-large-data-graphic)

[Plot compiled function with LogLinearPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174052/plot-compiled-function-with-loglinearplot)

Comment: Dd you intend that your two code snippets would have different `ContourPlot` calls?  They seem to be identical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. You specify the contours you want through the `Contours` option of the function, surprisingly.

```
f = Compile[{{x}, {y}}, x^2 + y^2];
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 1], 
 Contours -> {0.1}, ContourShading -> False]
```

Works beautifully. If you specify an equality in the argument ContourPlot defaults to symbolic solving which is usually way too slow.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
f = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, x^2 + y^2];
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0.1, {x, y} \[Element]Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't change anything. The problem is that when you specify a contour to plot, Mathematica reverts back to trying to symbolically solve the equality.

Comment: Contour is evaluated without error message, so obviously somthing changed.

Comment: Not for me. I am using Mathematica 11.2 so that might be why.

Answer (score 3):

The message you are getting means that `ContourPlot` internally is calling `f` with symbolic arguments contrary to its documentation.

> ContourPlot has attribute HoldAll, and evaluates the f<sub>i</sub> and g<sub>i</sub> only after assigning specific numerical values to x and y.

Nevertheless, many functions expect to be able to evaluate user-supplied functions symbolically.  There is [an idiomatic way](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502) to prevent these calls: tell the pattern matcher that the arguments must be numeric.

```
Clear[f, fCompiled];
fCompiled = Compile[{{x}, {y}}, x^2 + y^2];
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := fCompiled[x, y];
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0.1, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]
```

This produces no diagnostics.

There are two confusable conditions, `?NumberQ` and `?NumericQ`.  Since `NumberQ[Pi] == False`, `NumericQ[Pi] == True`, and `` fCompiled[Pi,Pi] == 19.739208802178716` ``, `NumberQ` is too strict.  Use `NumericQ`.

Comment: You can also add `RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False` to `Compile`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple more ideas for displaying the contour at $z=1/10$

You could also define a helper function `g` that forces `Plot3D` to work with numeric values. Note: this will give a symbolic rather than a numeric tooltip for the contour.

```
g[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := f[x, y];
ContourPlot[g[x, y] == 1/10, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ContourShading -> False]
```

[image: contour]

You could also show the contour on the 3D surface defined by `f`:

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[],
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
  Mesh -> {{{1/10, Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[3.5]]}}},
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/3},
  ColorFunction -> (White &),
  Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: surface]